# Cannot restart mysql server

Tags: server, mysql, cron

Whenever i try to restart mysql server it shows the following error

```
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

I tried restarting the server by using

```
service mysql start
```

But it shows the following error

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
 See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

service status mysql service shows the following

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Mon 2019-07-08 19:03:30 IST; 1
  Process: 4070 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit

Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, sch
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quic
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'start-limit
```

and the journalctl -xe shows the following:

```
 Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 08 19:03:30 arnab systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
Jul 08 19:05:01 arnab CRON[4094]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 08 19:05:01 arnab CRON[4095]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul 08 19:05:01 arnab CRON[4094]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

What is the error ?

The contents of the hosts file are as follows:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   arnab-HP-450-Notebook-PC
127.0.0.1   arnab

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: `mysql.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.` is the problem. See `tail -30 /var/log/mysql/error.log` just after you did the restart. `(13)` is a permission error. Maybe the database is busy recovering from an earlier crash and you need to wait for that to finish.

Comment: What should i do ?

Comment: How long should i wait....

Comment: @Rinzwind how long should i wait . i tried to remove all the sql files and then do everything from the beginning right from the installation but the same problem persists. Is it because of the problem in the hosts fiel

Comment: Did you check the log file? How long depends on the size of the databases. But only If that is the issue

Comment: The entire thing is sorted now . Thanks for your help